# OnClickListener won't work in some places of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-view

I put another `RecyclerView B` in a `RecyclerView A`.
I set an `OnClickListener` into the `ItemView` in the Adapter of the outer RecyclerView A.

When I click anywhere on the `ItemView` in `RecyclerView A`, OnClickListener will work well but when I click `RecyclerView B` in `ItemView`, My `OnClickListener` does not work anymore.
Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Comment: What code are you using for this? Please share your code to get better idea about this problem.

Comment: I think you better be using ExandablaeListView instead of RecyclerView inside RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way way to solve this problem is to give `OnClickListener` to adapter's main layout.

For eg:-

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_above="@+id/mainlayout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  ............ //more layout.

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Then give `OnClickListener` in adapter..

```
holder.mainlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Your code
        }
    });
```

This will work and solve your problem..